# Measurable complex-valued function

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I have just started a Real Analysis with Measure Theory course. The class uses Bartle's "The Elements of Integration and Lebesgue Measure." We haven't covered much so my tools are pretty limited. I am finding the following problem a bit hard, because we have only seen measurable functions $f:X \to \mathbb{R},$ and the problem deals with a measurable function $f:X \to \mathbb{C}.$ I think I should think of $\mathbb{C}$ as $R^2$ (but still we haven't covered anything in $R^d$ for $d>1.$)

> Let $f$ be a complex-valued function defined on a measurable space ($X$, $\Sigma$). Show that $f$ is $\Sigma-$measurable if and only if
>
> $\{x \in X:a<Re(f)(x)<b,c<Im(f)(x)<d\}$
>
> belongs to $\Sigma$ for all real numbers $a,b,c,d$. More generally, $f$ is $\Sigma-$measurable if and only if $f^{-1}(G)\in \Sigma$ for every open set $G$ in the complex plane.

This is the definition of measurable function that I have: $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable if $\forall a \in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}(a,\infty) \in \Sigma$. (The book also proves that we can substitute $\{(a,\infty): a \in \mathbb{R}\}$ with any other generating family of $B(\mathbb{R}))$.

In terms of a $\Sigma$-measurable complex-valued function, I have read and re-read the $2$ chapters we have covered so far and there is only one paragraph on $\Sigma$-measurable complex-valued functions, which reads: If $f$ is a complex-valued function defined on $X$ then there exist two uniquely determined real-valued functions $f_r$ and $f_i$ such that $f=f_r+if_i, f_r(x)=Ref(x)$ and $f_i(x)=Imf(x).$ We define the complex-valued function to be $\Sigma$-measurable if and only if its real and imaginary parts $f_r$ and $f_i$ are measurable.

This is what I have so far:

Let $R=I_1 \times I_2$ where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose $f$ is $\Sigma$-measurable, then $f_r$ and $f_i$ are $\Sigma$-measurable $\implies f_r^{-1}(I_1) \in \Sigma$ and $f_i^{-1}(I_2) \in \Sigma$.

I know it's not much, but I don't know how to continue because I don't know how to deal with $\mathbb{R}^2.$ I understand this is too much to ask but is there anyone who would be willing to write me a detailed proof (without skipping steps or writing "then it follows...") with explanations and using very basic tools. I would like to understand the proof well so I can get rid of my confusion.

Comment: Just treat it as two separate $\mathbb{R}$ valued functions $\operatorname{re} f$ and $\operatorname{im} f$. $f$ is measurable **iff** the real & imaginary parts are.

Comment: You’ve been here quite a while, so you know that a title such as “very confused, please help!” is not appreciated here. Please edit this, and also include more information about the goal and/or function itself in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is complex measurable. Then $\operatorname{re} f$ and $\operatorname{im} f$ are measurable in the ordinary sense and hence $(\operatorname{re} f)^{-1} ((a,b)) \cap (\operatorname{im} f)^{-1} ((c,d))$ is measurable.

Now suppose $(\operatorname{re} f)^{-1} ((a,b)) \cap (\operatorname{im} f)^{-1} ((c,d))$ is measurable for all $a,b,c,d$. Since $\mathbb{R} = \cup_n (-n,n)$ we see that 
$\cup_n ((\operatorname{re} f)^{-1} ((a,b)) \cap (\operatorname{im} f)^{-1} ((-n,n))) = (\operatorname{re} f)^{-1} ((a,b))$ is measurable and so $\operatorname{re} f$ is measurable. Similarly, $\operatorname{im} f$ is measurable and so $f$ is measurable.

**Note**:

From the point of view of measurability, $\mathbb{C}$ is treated as if it was $\mathbb{R}^2$ and you can deal with this in at least two equivalent ways.

A real valued function is considered (Borel) measurable **iff** $\{x| f(x) \le \alpha \}$ is measurable for all $\alpha$ ($<,>,\le,\ge$ are all equivalent in this regard).

(i) Bartle calls a function $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ measurable **iff** the functions $\operatorname{re} f$ and $\operatorname{im} f$ are real measurable.

(ii) You can call $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$ measurable **iff** $\{x | f(x) \in (-\infty, \alpha] \times (-\infty,\beta] \}$ is measurable for all $\alpha, \beta$.

It is not too hard to show that these are the same.

Comment: In the second paragraph don't we have to assume that for for all $(a,b) \cap (c,d), f^{-1}((a,b) \cap (c,d))$ is measurable. And from there try to show that $f_r$ and $f_i$ are measurable functions. Why are you supposing $f^{-1}_r(a,b) \cap f^{-1}_i(c,d)$ is measurable? Why is this $f^{-1}((a,b) \cap (c,d)) = f^{-1}_r(a,b) \cap f^{-1}_i(c,d)$ true? I am a bit confused on that part.

Comment: I am not following you. You are trying to show that the statement in the yellow box is true, correct? The first paragraph shows the only if, the second the if part. So given that $\{x \in X:a<Re(f)(x)<b,c<Im(f)(x)<d\} = (\operatorname{re} f)^{-1} ((a,b)) \cap (\operatorname{im} f)^{-1} ((c,d))$ is measurable for all $a,b,c,d$ you need to show that $\operatorname{re} f$ and $\operatorname{im} f$ are (real) measurable.

Comment: Note that $\{x \in X:a<Re(f)(x)<b,c<Im(f)(x)<d\} = f^{-1}((a,b) \times (c,d))$. (Or $(a,b)+i(c,d)$ if you prefer that notation.)

Comment: Remember that Bartle is **defining** $f$ to be measurable **iff** the real and imaginary parts are separately measurable as real valued functions.

Comment: Sorry, yes your second comment is related to what I was asking (I'll rewrite my comment because I wrote $\cap$ instead of $\times$): In the second paragraph (for the if part) we assume for all $(a,b) \times (c,d), f^{-1}((a,b) \times (c,d))$ is measurable. And from there try to show that $f_r$ and $f_i$ are measurable functions (which would imply $f$, the complex-valued function is measurable). My question is: Why did you start by assuming $f_r^{-1}(a,b) \cap f_i^{-1}(c,d) $ is measurable? I don't see why $f^{-1}((a,b) \times (c,d))=f_r^{-1}(a,b) \cap f_i^{-1}(c,d).$

Comment: And thank you for those notes!

Comment: $f(x) \in (a,b) \times (c,d)$ **iff** $\operatorname{re} f(x) \in (a,b)$ and $\operatorname{im} f(x) \in (c,d)$.